# how Dataframe class is imported directly from pandas package

Tags: python, pandas, python-import

in pandas we can directly do the following

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
```

here, pandas is a package. DataFrame is a class. So, how does this work because, DataFrame was actually defined in a `pandas.core.frame` ( it is defined in frame.py which is inside core folder of pandas.)

Note: i was thinking that this kind of behavior can be achieved by doing something in `__init__.py` file. Can anyone help me understand this.

Comment: everything imported in the `__init__.py` file of a python package will be available at the top-level of the package (you can restrict this behavior by creating a list named `__all__` in the `__init__.py` containing all the names you want to be available)

Comment: @Jacquot, thanks. this helped me to understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dataframe` as you said is defined in [pandas/core/frame.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.1/pandas/core/frame.py).

Let's take a look at  [pandas/__init__.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.1/pandas/__init__.py) in pandas [directory](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/tree/v0.23.1/pandas) on github.

Line 42:

```
from pandas.core.api import *
```

And [pandas/core/api.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.1/pandas/core/api.py) imports `Dataframe` from [pandas/core/frame.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.1/pandas/core/frame.py) in line 23:

```
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
```

So since you `import *` from `pandas/core/api.py` in `pandas/__init__.py` and `pandas/core/api.py` imports `Dataframe` then you have `Dataframe` imported directly to pandas.

Answer (score 4):

`__init__.py` is technically just another python module, so any name defined in a package's `__init__.py` is directly accessible from the package itself. And it's indeed a common pattern in Python to use a package's `__init__.py` as [a facade for submodules / subpackages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).

FWIW note that panda's `__init__.py`, while an example of using `__init__.py` as a facade, is not following good practices in that it uses "star imports" (`from submodule import *`) which makes it very painful to trace the origin of a name (the module where it is defined) - specially with such a large package as Panda - *and* is very brittle too since if two submodules export a same name the one imported last will shadow the first one. The good practice is to always explicitely specify which names you want to import:

```
from submodule1 import foo, bar
from submodule2 import baaz, quux
```

which makes clear where a name comes from and will make a duplicate name much more obvious:

```
from submodule1 import foo, bar
from submodule2 import baaz, quux
from submodule3 import foo # oops, we will have to rename either this one or submodule1.foo
```